# AJAX ASP.NET Remove URL ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, url

The site im working on is an Ajax enabled ASP.net/C# project and i have a URL like this:

http://localhost:2531/(S(lfcvqc55wkabpp55o1x4pvq5))/Logon.aspx

How do you get rid of the (S(lfcvqc55wkabpp55o1x4pvq5)) portion of the URL? I have a feeling its a web.config parameter however I'm not really sure what you call this part?

Comment: It's an identifier for your Session. If you remove it a new one will be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is your SessionId - check the `<sessionState>` element in web.config and you will likely see `<sessionState cookieless="true" />`

Set that to false and see how it goes. But keep in mind that session state will then be tracked by setting a cookie. It is possible that the designer of the site had a valid reason for using the url to track session. You should probably ask someone.

If you simply don't like the way it looks and want it gone, but did not consider that it is purposeful, perhaps you should *really* talk to someone with a nameplate and a door before doing anything.